# Error when using forecastHybrid with hts and external regressors during forecast

Tags: r, forecasting

I was trying to use `forecastHybrid` with hierarchical time series and external regressors but I cannot figure out how to do that. I am trying in this way:

```
library(hts)
library(forecastHybrid)

forecast(htseg1, a.args = list(xreg = data.frame(1:10)), models = "aet", 
xreg = data.frame(11:20), FUN = hybridModel)
```

But I got the following error:

`Error in forecast.Arima(object$auto.arima, h = h, xreg = xreg, level = level) : 
  No regressors provided`

Do you know the proper way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a clean solution right now but a nice workaround using the `combinef()` function has been proposed here:

https://github.com/ellisp/forecastHybrid/issues/74